# Monospace Font Consolas com Altura 15px e Largura 7px

Tags: javascript, html, css

Eu estou a tentar descobrir como é que posso ter um tamanho de letra que tenha sempre exatamente 7 pixeis de largura e 15 de altura em todas as letras/charateres.

Eu pensei que `font-family: consolas;` com `font-size: 12.73px;` era perfeito mas depois de testar com mais precisão (calculando o tamanho de 100 carateres) descobri o seguinte:

```js
function Atualizar(){
  document.getElementById('Font').style.fontSize = document.getElementById('Input').value + "px";
  document.getElementById('Horizontal').innerHTML = document.getElementById('Font').getBoundingClientRect().width;
  document.getElementById('Vertical').innerHTML = document.getElementById('Font').getBoundingClientRect().height;
}
Atualizar()
```

```css
span {
  font-family: consolas;
}
```

```html
<span id="Font">1234567890123456789012345678901234567890123456789012345678901234567890123456789012345678901234567890</span>
<br>
<br>
<span>Tamanho da font: </span><input id="Input" oninput="Atualizar()" value="12.739999294281004971196">
<br>
<span>Largura de 100 caratere: </span><span id="Horizontal"></span>
<br>
<span>Altura de 1 carateres: </span><span id="Vertical"></span>
```

Nota: depois de escrever, ler e ouvir tanto Inglês online já não faço ideia se escrevo em Português character, caractere, carátere, caracteres, caráteres, etc. Eu leio caratere e carateres (letra).

Comment: aqui tem os vários termos usados para caractere: https://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Caractere

Comment: Obrigado @TomásAntunes. ^^

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Eu também [perguntei esta questão no StackOverflow Inglês](https://stackoverflow.com/q/42646339/7393973) e recebi a [solução](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42646712/7393973) de usar `letter-spacing: 0.001px;` o que eu não tenho a certeza se é perfeito mas é perto o suficiente.

Mesmo assim, se alguém ainda tiver uma resposta melhor, eu fico agradecido.
Isto é algo que me chateia bastante mas não tanto agora com este truque.

Eu estou a criar um editor de texto que vai utilizar bastante JavaScript e posicionamento automático.